# Receiving SMS in C# with RingCentral

Tags: c#, sms, ringcentral

I am able to send SMS using C#.    But my problem is I don't know to receive those SMS.

I looked into following documentation with WebHook and C# here:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/notifications/quick-start/webhook/c-sharp

But not sure how to do it exactly.

Can I get any help to know how I can receive the SMS. Any sample will be great.

Comment: Why is the sample on the page you linked not sufficient?

Comment: I am very new to this.. I went through this but not sure with ngrok usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 ways to receive SMS:

- PubNub Subscription
- WebHook Subscription
- API Request

Here are some details:

1. Using ***PubNub***, you can receive SMS.
   Check it out here: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp-client/blob/master/RingCentral.Test/SubscripotionTest.cs#L31
   Since this is used by ***PubNub***, so you don't need `ngrok`
2. If you want ***WebHook***, you need to subscribe for ***push notification*** check the reference demo: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp-client/blob/master/RingCentral.Test/WebHookTest.cs
3. The ***direct API*** of RingCentral APIs to receive SMS content in your *C#*, by calling this API inside your SDK is:     `/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/message-store/{messageId}/content/{attachmentId}`. Here you need to put the ***message id*** and the ***attachment id*** to retrieve message content from ***message-store***

Hope this help.